# In Visual Basic how do I make a list of subfolders underneath a folder I have a path for when loading the program?

Tags: vb.net

I have a file structure for VB as
initial folder
sub 1 folder
sub sub folder 1
SUB SUB FOLDER 2
.
.
. sub n folder

I want to put the name of 1 through n folder as items in a strip menu and save the paths to be used later to access the files in the sub folders. I only want the sub xxx names and not the sub SUB names

I tried this

```
    Dim appPath As String = Application.StartupPath()
    Dim n As Integer, patt As String

    '  Dim DirectoryList As ArrayList
    '  Dim listbox1 As String
    n = InStr(appPath, "bin")
    patt = LSet(appPath, n - 1)
    TextBox2.Text = n
    TextBox1.Text = appPath
    TextBox3.Text = patt

    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim directorylist As ArrayList

    ListBox1.Items.Clear()

    Dim folderpath = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(patt, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.txt")

    For Each foldername As System.IO.Path In folderPath
        ListBox1.Items.Add(foldername)
    Next
```

Comment: You say that you want folders yet you have code that gets text files. How do you expect that to do anything useful?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [System.IO.Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=netframework-4.7.2)

In your case you can try something like this:

```
Dim directoryList() As String = Directory.GetDirectories(patt, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do this to just get the names of the first level of subfolders.
Here it is .
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
    Dim appPath As String = Application.StartupPath()
    Dim n, lengthpath As Integer, patt, patt1 As String

    '  Dim listbox1 As String
    n = InStr(appPath, "bin")
    patt = LSet(appPath, n - 14) + "Data\"
    TextBox2.Text = n
    TextBox1.Text = appPath
    TextBox3.Text = patt
    lengthpath = Len(patt) + 1

    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    Dim fileNames = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(patt, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.*")
    For Each fileName As String In fileNames
        patt1 = Mid(fileName, lengthpath)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(patt1)
    Next

End Sub
```